# how do i use AutoMapper in ICollation<> Fields

Tags: automapper, icollection

when i use AutoMapper for mapping my ViewModels and get All News, thrown error for me.

Errors...
The following property on Mosque.Core.ViewModels.CategoryViewModel cannot be mapped: 
Categories
Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the destination type Mosque.Core.ViewModels.CategoryViewModel.

please help me, thank you

//Models

```
public class News
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<News> News { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<News> News { get; set; }
}
```

//ViewModels

```
public class NewsViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CategoryViewModel> Categories { get; set; }
    public virtual UserViewModel User { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<NewsViewModel> News { get; set; }
}

public class UserViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<NewsViewModel> News { get; set; }
}
```

how do i use for select All News?

**--Update1--**

I used onion architecture in the project and i installed AutoMapper in the Service layer and i want get all news from repository and fill into ViewModels and pass to the UI.
my code in service layer is...

```
public List<NewsViewModel> GetAll()
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<News, NewsViewModel>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Categories, src => src.MapFrom(p => p.Categories))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.User, src => src.MapFrom(p => p.User));
    Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    var viewModels = new List<NewsViewModel>();
    foreach (var item in _newsRepository.GetAll())
    {
        var viewModel = Mapper.Map<News, NewsViewModel>(item);
        viewModels.Add(viewModel);
    }
    return viewModels;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you create the maps and the code where you map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to have created maps for `Catagory` and `User`.

Add the following maps:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserViewModel>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Category, CategoryViewModel>();
```

By the way, why are you creating the maps inside the `GetAll` method? You can create the maps once, usually at application startup.

Comment: thank you, and about your suggestion...
I used onion architecture in project ,i installed AutoMapper in the Service layer and i don't know how do i implement "application startup" in this layer.
if you guide me about this, I thank you : )

Comment: I wouldn't create the maps every method call. At least put them in the constructor of the class that will use them. You can also use dependency injection and inject a `IMappingEngine` to this class and let another class be responsible for creating the maps. You can find a lot of material about AutoMapper and dependency injection online.